# JSONObject динамически изменяется, как его обойти?

Tags: java, json, android-studio

парсится такой JSON:
{"ChampionLA54":{"availability":1,"brand":"Champion","description":"","number":"LA54","numberFix":"LA54"},"GOTTWALDLA54":{"availability":1,"brand":"GOTTWALD","description":"","number":"LA54","numberFix":"LA54"},"Mahle/KnechtLA54":{"availability":1,"brand":"Mahle/Knecht","description":"Фильтр, воздух во внутренном пространстве","number":"LA54","numberFix":"LA54"}}

Пытаюсь получить так:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonresponce = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject userInfo = jsonresponce.getJSONObject("ChampionLA54");
            brsndP = userInfo.getString("brand");
            artP = userInfo.getString("number");
            nalP = userInfo.getString("availability");
            desP = userInfo.getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

но переменная "ChampionLA54" динамически изменяется, как распарсить ответ обходя "ChampionLA54", "GOTTWALDLA54", "Mahle/KnechtLA54"?

Comment: Брать массив всех полученных обектов и в цикле перебирать. У Вас явно приходит JsonArray т.к. множество объектов не может храниться в респонсе начинающегося с символа "{"

Comment: Массив всех полученных объектов не известен и его результаты могут быть разными.

Comment: Так я Вам и говорю - JSONArray в помощь